# Issue refactoring curiously recurring template pattern

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

The following code fails to compile on g++ 4.6.1:

```
template<class Base>
struct GetBase {
  Base * getBase() {
    return static_cast<Base *>(this);
  }
};

template<class Derived>
struct Parent : private GetBase<Derived> {
  using GetBase<Derived>::getBase;
  int y() {
    return getBase()->x();
  }
};

struct Child : public Parent<Child> {
  int x() {
    return 5;
  }
  int z() {
    return y();
  }
};
```

with the error

```
In member function ‘Base* GetBase<Base>::getBase() [with Base = Child]’:
    instantiated from ‘int Parent<Derived>::y() [with Derived = Child]’
    instantiated from here
error: ‘GetBase<Child>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Child’
```

Changing the static_cast to a reinterpret_cast will get the code to compile and it will work in this case, but I'm wondering if this is an acceptable solution in all cases?  i.e., is it ever the case that a pointer to a base class is not the same as this?  I'm assuming with multiple inheritance this may happen if the parents have data members?  If GetBase is the first superclass, are the this pointers guaranteed to be equal?

Comment: I'm shocked this compiles on VS2010 ... regardless you should probably refactor your design.

Comment: Yes there are cases where reinterpret_cast<> will break and most of them are completely implementation defined.

Comment: At the very least consider removing the infinite levels of `getBase()` and prefer `dynamic_cast` to determine derived from a base class pointer.

Comment: FYI virtual methods could probably simplify this crazy inheritance scheme.

Comment: @AJG85- The whole point of this setup (the CRTP) is to avoid dynamic polymorphism and to handle everything at compile-time.  Adding in virtual methods and `dynamic_cast` would defeat the purpose of the design.

Comment: @templatetypedef Is that desirable? I suppose there might be less cost but programmers are significantly more expensive than hardware usually.

Comment: The names GetBase, getBase, and Base are quite misleading, because in fact you convert a pointer to a derived type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question; it caused me to learn something new about `static_cast`.

I think the following code achieves what you want : provides a base class for CRTP with a member function that casts `this` to the Derived type, yet only makes it accessible to the direct descendants of this base class. It compiles with GCC 4.3.4 ([tested at ideone](http://ideone.com/fAcgA)) and Clang (tested at llvm.org). Sorry, I couldn't resist to changing the names that I find confusing.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
class CRTP {
protected:
  Derived * derived_this() {
    return static_cast<Derived *>(this);
  }
};

template<class Derived>
struct Parent : public CRTP<Derived> {
private:
  using CRTP<Derived>::derived_this;
public:
  int y() {
    return derived_this()->x();
  }
};

struct Child : public Parent<Child> {
  int x() {
    return 5;
  }
  int z() {
    return y();
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << Child().z() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This variant works because the inheritance is public, which enables the standard conversion of a pointer-to-derived-class to a pointer-to-base-class, and so also the inverse conversion (from base to derived) with `static_cast`, which CRTP needs. Private inheritance in your code prohibited this. So I made inheritance public, changed the method to be protected, and in `Parent` further restricted access by putting the `using` declaration into private section.

Comment: +1 and thanks for this answer. It saved me truckload of debugging. MSVC++ 2012 Express still compiles with private inheritance...

Answer (score 3):

*I'm wondering if this is an acceptable solution in all cases?*

**No.**  (See below)

*is it ever the case that a pointer to a base class is not the same as this?*

**Yes.**

- With multiple inheritance, the base classes can not be expected to have the same address.
- Depending on the compiler, a derived class with a vtable pointer may not have the same `this` as a base class that has no vtable pointer.

When explicitly upcasting to a base, `static_cast` is the appropriate C++ cast.